# Unit Test - No qualifying bean of type ERROR

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to unit test my rest api controller. Controller code is as below

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/events")
    public class EventController {

        @Autowired
        private EventService eventService;

        @GetMapping
        public Iterable<Event> getEvents(EventSearchFilter filter, @PageableDefault(page = 1, size = 5, sort = "location.city, asc") Pageable pageable) {
            return eventService.findEventsOnCondition(filter, pageable);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Test class is

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(EventController.class)
public class EventEndpointTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private EventController eventController;

    @Mock
    private EventService eventService;

    @InjectMocks
    private PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableArgumentResolver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(eventController).setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getEvents() throws Exception{
        Event event = new Event();
        event.setName("TestName");
        EventSearchFilter filter = new EventSearchFilter();
        filter.setName("TestName");
        List<Event> eventList = singletonList(event);
        given(eventController.getEvents(any(EventSearchFilter.class), any(PageRequest.class))).willReturn(eventList);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/events")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
    ...
}
```

However, I got error complaining saying I have Error creating bean with name 'eventController':

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'EventService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}.
```

As I got above error, I tried use Autowired annotation for my EventService. It still doesn't work. any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution. All I need to do is replacing `@WebMvcTest(EventController.class)` in my Test class to `@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)`. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare @Service annotation at EventService?

```
@Service
public class EventService {
 ...something code..
}
```

I guess Spring cannot find bean named EventService

Comment: yes. I did. My controller works fine with @autowired private EnventSerrvice eventService. This issue only occurs for my unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the stack trace showed

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'i18NService'; 
...
...
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '...Service' available:
...
...
...
```

and ultimately the solution was that the services needed to be mocked with `@MockBean` since regular components (including services and repositories) will not be scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer with @DFeng. Encountered the below error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mysqlRedisCachingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mysqlRedisBusinessService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mysqlRedisBusinessService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mysqlRedisService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mysqlRedisService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mysqlRedisRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.caching.redismanager.repo.MysqlRedisRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.caching.redismanager.repo.MysqlRedisRepository' in your configuration.
```

This annotation did the trick.

```
@MockBean
```

Added the below in the Test Class:

```
@MockBean
private MysqlRedisRepository mysqlRedisRepository;

@Test
void contextLoads() {}
```

It works as expected. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a real component instance to your Spring Test Context (instead of mocking beans) you can always use **@TestConfiguration** annotation and create a nested static class that defines beans.

For my simple example it could be

```
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        public UserService userService() {
            return new UserService();
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup, our test is now able to load the Spring Test Context. You can
even inject all collaborators to your controller. This solution gives us a lot of control as we can decide for every collaborator to either mock it or provide the actual implementation.